# Angular 2 rc5 , unit testing issue with services

Tags: angular, jasmine

```
@Injectable()
export class Service1 {
    constructor( private s2 : Service2 ) { 
        console.log( s2.name );
     }
}

@Injectable()
export class Service2 {
    public name: string = 'Hi';
}


//------------Test-------------

let service1: MockService1;  // MockService1 extends Service1
let service2: MockService2;  // MockService2 extends Service2

beforeEach(() => {
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
        providers: [
            { provide: Service1, useClass: MockService1 },
            { provide: Service2, useClass: MockService2 }
        ]
    })
});  

beforeEach(inject( [ Service1 , Service2 ], ( s1: MokcService1 , s2: MockService2  ) => { 
    service1 = s1;
    service2 = s2; 
}));

it('should be defined ', () => {
    expect( service1 ).toBeDefined(); 
    expect( service2 ).toBeDefined();
});
```

I'm getting

TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating 's2.name')

because Service2 is undefined.

The same code worked earlier with addProviders and provide

```
beforeEach(() => {
    addProviders([
        provide(Service1, {useClass: MockService1 } ),
        provide(Service2, {useClass: MockService2 } ),
    ]);
});
```

Those 2 tests are passing when console.log( s2.name ) is removed

Any Idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use @Inject when injecting the service in the constructor,

Example:

```
constructor( @Inject(Service2) private s2 : Service2 ) { 
    console.log( s2.name );
}
```

Comment: Your code should use `@Inject(...)` not `$Inject(...)` and there is probably a problem somewhere else if you need `@Inject(xxx)` wher `xxx` is the same as the type of the parameter.

Comment: ah yes,  @Inject,  that was a typo